# How to do a ajax slide show?

Tags: javascript, ajax, slideshow

If you visit this page:    http://basecamphq.com/tour/

and click on the tour left hand side options: communicate, share files, deliver-on-time you will see that the tour works like a slide show when you click it shows you the next slide.  How can i implement this for my website.. are they using javascript or ajax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple Content Slider that can be implemented using simple content slider using jQuery.

Here is [Implementation Cookbook](http://brenelz.com/blog/build-a-content-slider-with-jquery/) and a [Simple Demo](http://ennuidesign.com/demo/contentslider/)

remember its just a simple demo and you can do every thing you want just using this simple plugin.

Comment: So i can have it display database entries?!!

Comment: But will users have to have plugins too?

Comment: Yea, you can render any thing you want even data came from database
Your users and clients does not need to have any thing. you will add javascript code to your html body and every thing will go fine.

Answer (score 1):

They are using Jquery,

This is the specific glide effect they are using: http://code.google.com/p/missingmethod-projects/wiki/Glider

If you want more kinds of it you can use http://www.hacktweaks.com/2010/02/15-awesome-jquery-based-content-slidesowglider-for-your-blogwebsite.html Each one of this examples contains a demo and and explanation, and the jquery code you will have to put in the web page.

Comment: Thanks.  But will my users have to have plugins for them too?

Comment: @AAA No.  You will have to include all necessary javascript files on your page.  Your users will not need to do anything special.

Comment: No, jquery is just a javascript library you upload to your server(just like javascript) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery. No one will have to download any plugin.